# How to change the list of characters that MacOS QuickLook displays when previewing font files (ttf, otf etc)

Tags: macos, fonts, quicklook

By default MacOS's built in QuickLook feature displays only latin characters + figures when previewing font files. This is what it looks like:

[typical QuickLook preview window for a font file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfOmz.png)

I need to be able to quickly see if the font contains non-latin characters, for example Cyrillic. I am sure there is a way to edit some .plist file inside macOS to modify the list of characters that QuickLook shows for a font in order to add some non latin characters. I even did it once, but it was a few releases of MacOS ago, when System and Library folders were not hidden and thus were searchable.

Could someone please advise, where this .plist file may be located now in MacOS (HighSierra)? Thanks!

Comment: Found a solution myself: 

The various character sets that QuickLook presents are based on the language which is the primary language you are using. The character sets are are kept in a file called SampleSupport.plist which is found at:

/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Copy this path and in Finder go: Command + Shift + G and paste the path into the field and you will instantly brought to the right place.

Edit the file in your favourite editor. Edit the EN char string to add some non-latin chars.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself:

The various character sets that QuickLook presents are based on the language which is the primary language you are using. The character sets are are kept in a file called SampleSupport.plist which is found at:

/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Copy this path and in Finder go: Command + Shift + G and paste the path into the field and you will instantly brought to the right place.

Edit the file in your favourite editor. Edit the EN char string to add some non-latin chars.

[editing SampleSupport.plist to show non-latin characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8WlI.jpg)